# Optimize load balancer SSL termination on a Windows machine

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache-2.4, iis

I have an application on a 32-bit Apache server on a Windows machine from a 3rd party vendor. (Can't change that).

The setup:

- Traffic is HTTPS, port 443.
- Apache web app service
- Activemq service
- Application service

Each service listens on a different port.

There are many concurrent requests, but they are coming from the same sources.

We can't offload the SSL termination to an external server, because for security reason, all traffic between server must be encrypted.

Our initial configuration was using apache mod_proxy to direct traffic to the other services.

Up to a certain load it worked well. But it is limited to ThreadsPerChild of 700.  Apache 32-bit does not allow increasing it.

We tried using nginx as a load balancer. On Windows, it limits worker_connections to 1024. But it can't handle more than 500 requests because of SSL termination. We tried to optimize SSL termination of nginx, but it didn't improve the results.
We tried several nginx SSL termination and caching configurations, but we haven't seen any improvement in results.

```
ssl_ciphers '...';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m; 
ssl_session_timeout 10m; 
ssl_session_tickets on;
ssl_buffer_size 4k; 
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

We tested both Apache and nginx, and they can handle up to 5000 normal unencrypted HTTP connections.

## Update

This is the error when trying to have `worker_connections=4096` together with SSL:

[image]

How to solve this issue?

By the way: We are not locked on Apache or Nginx. If anyone knows on any other reverse proxy solution that works well on Windows, let us know.

Comment: What version of MS-Windows? IIRC versions other than "server" enforce a limit of the number of connections (to make you go buy a server licence).

Comment: It is "Windows Server 2019"

Comment: You could try increasing the number of worker processes, but using a larger number than the number of CPUs is not recommended. That leaves the options of recompiling nginx with a larger FD_SETSIZE ( http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html ) or switching to a different OS

Comment: `We are not locked on Apache or Nginx.` how would you even be at this point without at least considering the number of processors?

Comment: The machine has 4 cores. As far as I have seen, there is one nginx process per core. However, according to https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues: `Although several workers can be started, only one of them actually does any work`